# Proving that $f(n,m) = 3^n5^m$ is injective.

Tags: functions

> The function $f:\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ is defined by
>
> $$f(n,m) = 3^n5^m$$
>
> Determine if it is surjective and/or injective.

It isn't surjective, because $2$ in the codomain has no preimage.

As for injective... I could not think of a counterexample, so I guess it is. However, I failed to prove that. My attempt was something like:

Have some $(a,b),(c,d) \in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$:
$$f(a,b) = f(c,d)$$

$$3^a5^b=3^c5^d$$

$$\frac{3^a}{3^c}=\frac{5^b}{5^d}$$

$$\textrm{some mathematical voodo here}$$

$$a =c \land b = d$$

The intended proof is incomplete and/or wrong or it isn't actually injective.

How can I determine whether this function is injective?

Comment: Do you know the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)?

Comment: @AymanHourieh: Of couurseeee.. No, I fear not. I will check it out, thank you.

Comment: Omega, compare the fundamental theorem of arithmetic with the following question: would the map $f(n,m) = 2^n 4^m$ be injective? Would the map $f(n,m) = 2^n 3^m$ be? What about $50^n 11^m$?

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

$$3^a5^b=3^c5^d\iff 3^{a-c}=5^{d-b}\iff a-c=d-b=0\iff (a=c)\;\wedge\;(b=d)$$

Now, the second double implication follows at once from the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)...though, of course, if you rely on the FTA then you can "jump" from the first equality to the last part.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer is wrong, but let's give it a try anyway. We'll try do prove the injectivity by induction.

Lets take pairs of $n$ and $m$ belonging to the set $\{0,1,2\}$. In that case, we get that $f(0,0) = 1$, $f(0,1)=5$, $f(1,0) = 3$, $f(1,1) = 3\cdot5=15$, $f(1,2) =  3\cdot5^2 = 75$, $f(2,1) = 3^2\cdot5=45$, $f(2,2) = 3^2\cdot5^2=225$. As we can see, this condition holds true because 3 and 5 are coprimes.

We can see that for those initial values, each pair $f(m,n)$ was different from each other.

Now, let's assume that for each value of $x$ and $y$; $1\le x\le m$ and $1\le y \le n$, the hypothesis holds true, that is, that the function is injective for each value of $x$ and $y$ until $m$ and $n$.

Now, let's try to see what happens with values of $m+1$ and $n+1$:

$f(m+1,n) = 3^{m+1}\cdot 5^n = 3\cdot3^m\cdot5^n$

$f(m,n+1) = 3^{m}\cdot 5^{n+1} = 5\cdot3^m\cdot5^n$

$f(m+1,n+1) = 3^{m+1}\cdot 5^{n+1} = 15\cdot3^m\cdot5^n$

Since $f(m+1,n) \neq f(m,n+1) \neq f(m+1,n+1)$, we have that the function is injective for $n+1$ and $m+1$ and, therefore, by induction, is injective for any pair $n,m$. The key factor here is, again, the fact that both values are coprime, and if they cannot share any common integer between them, for $m+1$ and $n+1$, they won't be able to share it for any $n$ and $m$.